# Code Igniter route translation

Tags: codeigniter, uri, translation

I'm using URI Language Identifier library to internationalize my website :
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier

With this Helper we can have url like this :

- /mywebsite/fr/home
- /mywebsite/en/home

But I'm searching a smart and simple solution to create easily urls like this :

- fr -> /mywebsite/accueil
- en -> /mywebsite/home

I was wondering if it was possible to use the language files in the routes to avoid duplications ?

Thank you